# How can i manipulate the values of a select list coming from a dictionary?

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have a dictionary filled with keys(ints) and the value, which is a datetime. On my razor view im now displaying it into a dropdown menue. Which works perfectly fine but im wondering if its possible to add text to the value for example my value would be the 17.07.2019, could i do it that it says "Date: 17.07.2019" in the dropdown? so what i mean is for example adding a string to it?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
 m => m.SelectedWeek, 
 new SelectList(Model.Calenderweeks, "Key", "Value"), 
 "Select", new {
                disableValidation = "true",
                onchange = @"
                form.submit();"
               })
}
```

i tried manipulating it like this:

```
new SelectList(Model.Calenderweeks, "Key", "Date: Value"),
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to have a string as value instead of a datetime. When you insert the keys and values into your dictionary, you could just do:

```
string value = string.format("Date: {0}", datetime.ToShortDateString());
```